# Отслеживание drop'а на элементе

Tags: javascript

Всем привет)
Нужно определить, когда элемент #drag будет перемещён на элемент #drop, но у меня возникли проблемы с условием.
Код: http://jsfiddle.net/hW23j/

Вот участок кода, в котором, как я думаю, сама проблема:

```
if((e.pageX >= dropX) && (e.pageX < (dropX + dropW)) && (e.pageY >= dropY) && (e.pageY <= (dropY + dropH)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что dropX и прочие ваши переменные получаемые из стиля содержат суффикс `px`. Сделайте parseInt(dropX), все будет работать. [ваш пример](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanovsuper/hW23j/2/)

Comment: Блин.. моя невимательность меня погубит) Спасибо большое)